# How to read XML file whith invalid character

Tags: java, xml, encryption

During development of the project in which it is necessary to encrypt the data read from the XML file, and then write to another file and decrypt it. The problem is that when reading the encrypted file, XML service symbols appear which are not read and give an error. The question is how do I read data from a file?
[Encryption Algorithms](https://github.com/nshusa/crypto-util)
Listing of code where I read file

`try {
                File file = new File(filePath);
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = 
    documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
                password = 
    document.getElementsByTagName("KeyWord").item(0).getTextContent();
                encDataAES = 
    document.getElementsByTagName("AES").item(0).getTextContent();
                encDataRSA = 
    document.getElementsByTagName("RSA").item(0).getTextContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error reading configuration file:");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }`

Comment: first of all if your XML is encoded by XML escape, you need to unescape it using Apache StringEscapeUtils. to handle this error, you have to play with string escape characters a bit.

Comment: Consider using standard XMLenc which avoids this problem by [base64 encoding the ciphertext](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#sec-CipherData)